# Is Matrix > Entries > Matrix possible?

Tags: entries, matrix

I have a matrix field with an entries field which ties into another matrix field. Is this possible? Here's what I have so far...

```
{% for block in entry.contentMatrix %}

  {# Tabs Block Type #}
  {% if block.type == "tabs" %}
    {% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(block.tabEntry) %}

    {% for entry in entries %}
      {# Matrix Content #}
      {% for block in entry.tabsMatrix.type('videoChannel, videoPlayer, copy') %}
        {{ block.title }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

This does not produce an error, just nothing.

Comment: As an aside, is the `switch` tag better suited than the conditional for looping through the block types? Is there a performance difference?

Comment: No performance difference in conditional vs switch. Switch is just a bit cleaner sometimes.

Comment: Your code looks ok to me. You might want to dump variables (or test length) within each loop to see if your getting results. i.e. `{{ dump(entries) }}` or `{{ entries|length }}`

Comment: The dump helped me realize that nothing was getting passed before getting to the matrix loop...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, I just have to pass the matrix fields handle `block` instead of `block.tabEntry`. Craft will automatically look for a relationship field (how smart). If you have multiple relation fields, you have to  use the dot notation with the field name. (→ see [Relations – Going Through Matrix](https://craftcms.com/docs/relations))

I still don't understand why using the dot notation would break it, but it apparently does. I checked my field name several times. Anywho, thanks for the help all!

```
{% for block in entry.contentMatrix %}

  {# Tabs Block Type #}
  {% if block.type == "tabs" %}
  {% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(block) %}

    {% for entry in entries %}
      {# Matrix Content #}
      {% for block in entry.tabsMatrix.type('videoChannel, videoPlayer, copy') %}
        {{ block.title }}
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to [filter by block type](https://craftcms.com/docs/matrix-fields#filtering-by-block-type)?

Maybe something like this:

```
{% for block in entry.contentMatrix %}

    {# Tabs Block Type #}
    {% if block.type == "tabs" %}

        {% set entries = craft.entries.relatedTo(block.tabEntry) %}

        {% for entry in entries %}
            {# Matrix Content #}
            {% for content in entry.tabsMatrix.type('videoChannel, videoPlayer, copy') %}

                {% if content.type == "videoChannel" %}
                    {{ content.title }}
                {% elseif content.type == "videoPlayer" %}
                    {{ content.url }}
                {% else %}
                    {{ content.text }}
                {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}

        {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Note: Matrix Content vars (*.title, *url, *text) are just examples.

Comment: My understanding is that we can add type to the `for` to choose multiple matrix types.